# Spline script is not working on my WordPress site, why?

Tags: wordpress, spline

I'm trying to add the following Spline code to my WordPress site using the "Code" element, but nothing happens when I save and look at the site:

```
<script type="module" src="https://unpkg.com/@splinetool/viewer@1.0.51/build/spline-viewer.js"></script>
<spline-viewer url="https://prod.spline.design/k6c8Ob15ZlM1EPMj/scene.splinecode"></spline-viewer>
```